# Harmonic oscillator

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve the simple pendulum in python. My goal is to save my results into a file in order to make a plot afterwards. Should I put my the code that saves the data in the loop or define a new function ?

NB: I'm a beginner.

Thank you.

```
import numpy as np

g = 9.8
L = 3

THETA_0 = np.pi / 4
THETA_DOT_0 = 0

def get_theta_double_dot(theta):
    return - (g / L) * np.sin(theta)

def theta(t):
    theta = THETA_0
    theta_dot = THETA_DOT_0

    dela_t = 0.01
    for tps in np.arange(0, t, delta_t):
        theta_double_dot = get_theta_double_dot(theta)
        theta = theta + (theta_dot * delta_t)
        theta_dot = theta_dot + (theta_double_dot * delta_t)
    return theta
```

Comment: Technically a pendulum is NOT a harmonic oscillator. Only for very small angles you can use this approximation

Comment: Maybe this is better suited for [Code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), as the question is more about the style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely store your results in a variable, and then save the whole thing into a file afterwards. Saving during the loop is "messy" and less efficient because of I/O calls constantly.

Note that this is not true if you are dealing with millions of entries, in which case you'd have to spare memory a bit and write to file in "batches". But it doesn't feel like this should be a problem in your case.